# Get specific from Zone - To Zone data - Sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table name entrystate i only want those vehicle data which left X zone and Enter in (A,B,C,D,E) zone, O state mean left and 1 mean Enter in Zone

```
  ZoneId  VehId      TimeFirst                     State
    X       1    2016-07-01 00:39:25                 0
    x       2    2016-07-01 00:50:25                 0
    x       1    2016-07-01 00:52:25                 0
    x       2    2016-07-01 00:53:25                 0
    A       1    2016-07-02 12:50:25                 1
    A       1    2016-07-02 14:50:25                 1
    A       1    2016-07-04 15:50:25                 1
    f       3    2016-07-03 14:50:25                 0
    A       3    2016-07-04 14:50:25                 1
    B       2    2016-07-02 00:50:25                 1
```

required result

```
  fromZone  Tozone VehId      FromTime                   ToTime        
    X        A       1    2016-07-01 00:52:25         2016-07-02 12:50:25       
    x        B       2    2016-07-01 00:53:25         2016-07-02 00:50:25
```

Comment: Please add solution formate

Comment: @Anup solution formate add

Comment: What SQL Version do you use ?, because SQL Server 2016 has a new function to switch zones from values.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Sql server 2012

Comment: @Doe, I meant AT TIME ZONE, but I have re-read your post and I see that this is not what you asked. Sorry.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Question update  please check

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
declare @table table (ZoneId nvarchar(2),VehId int,TimeFirst datetime ,[state] int
)

 insert into @table
      select    'X',       1,'2016-07-01 00:39:25',                 0
union all select     'x',       2,'2016-07-01 00:50:25',                 0
union all select     'x',       1,'2016-07-01 00:52:25',                 0
union all select     'x',       2,'2016-07-01 00:53:25',                 0
union all select     'A',       1,'2016-07-02 12:50:25',                 1
union all select     'A',       1,'2016-07-02 14:50:25',                 1
union all select     'A',       1,'2016-07-04 15:50:25',                 1
union all select     'f',       3,'2016-07-03 14:50:25',                 0
union all select     'A',       3,'2016-07-04 14:50:25',                 1
union all select     'B',       2,'2016-07-02 00:50:25',                 1


    SELECT t1.ZoneId AS fromZone
    ,t1.vehId
    ,t2.ZoneId AS ToZone
    ,max(t1.TimeFirst) AS FromTime
    ,min(t2.TimeFirst) AS ToTime
FROM @table t1
INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t1.VehId = t2.VehId
WHERE t1.ZoneId = 'X'
    AND t2.ZoneId IN ('A', 'B', 'f')
GROUP BY t1.ZoneId
    ,t1.vehId
    ,t2.ZoneId
```

**OUTPUT**

```
fromZone     vehId  ToZone          FromTime                ToTime
    X           1       A   2016-07-01 00:52:25.000     2016-07-02 12:50:25.000
    x           2       B   2016-07-01 00:53:25.000     2016-07-02 00:50:25.000
```

Comment: still same demo i have 10 rows

Comment: dear demo shown wrong output please look at required result

Comment: wrong data i want more than 7 months data without including Date in Grouping you couldn't find exact result